# Noise function guaranteed to have unique values inside a certain limit

Tags: noise

Is there any formula to produce a coherent noise, where it is guaranteed that no 2 unique values will be present inside any subset of size `s` ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean, perhaps by example? Are there are "bins" and the noise can appear only once in a bin?

Comment: @user619894 thanks for asking! I can provide program code which generates an eligible sample. The logic is the following:  for each point in the target space a random value is set; Then The logic checks for each point if any  in-range points have a similar value, and if it does the value of the cell is modified to another random value. It is a greedy way of generating it, but it works. I can Detail these steps in the answer if that would help.

Comment: If the rng has a repeat length much longer than the number of points, this should be very rare event, even for very distant points. In fact, it is probably easier to generate streams of globally unique pseudo randoms than to specifically demand them to be distinct in regions.

Comment: Indeed it is a rare occurrence, but I believe there should be a mathematical formulae to satisfy such requirements

Comment: A standard rng has no notion of distance. You can try casting out all duplicates before applying , or maybe some trick with hash tables.  As a physical model this sounds like a large q Potts model with antiferromagnetic interactions: nearby neighbors don't like to have  the same q value. maybe there is something relevant in the physics literature.